# Express and Redis - If session exists for this user, don't allow access

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I am using Redis and Express like this:

```
// app.js
var redis         = require('redis'),
    redisClient   = redis.createClient(),
    session       = require('express-session'),
    RedisStore    = require('connect-redis')(session);

session = session({
  store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient}), 
  secret: 'secretKey',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
})
```

app.use(session);

In my index route file, I set a user session like this:

```
req.session.user = user;
```

When this user comes back (or opens another tab), how could I detect how many sessions he is currently having and block him access if he already has one active session?

Answer (score 0):

`express-session` working via cookies. So you had cookie named `session` with some sessionId. All tabs inside browsed share cookies and you can't  rely on cookies if you want to strict working via only one browser tab.

You need to create your own Sessions for each opened browser tab. Something like generating tabId at client side and saving `{userId, tabId}` to Redis

Or you can use websockets (http://socket.io/) for that, a little overhead, but doing exactly what you want

Comment: Thank you. I understand the method. Although how would it work with socket.io?

Comment: socket.io create new socket connection with unique id for each opened tab. So you can manage the list of ids and reject connections with the same userId